# npm run script not writed in package

Tags: node.js, npm, development-environment, react-boilerplate

I can not find some doc in my help. In my npm project I have the script start

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server"
```

I must invoke the script start with one or more vars from cli (I can not change the package.json), example:

```
npm run start OTHER=1000
```

the "OTHER" is a var how is NODE_ENV, but is it possibile write (I know is it not possibile, I ask you some solution to do it):

```
npm run cross-env NODE_ENV=development OTHER=1000 node server
```

Comment: for my specific case i can install cross-env in global ( npm install cross-env -g ) and after run from my cli cross-env NODE_ENV=development OTHER=1000 node server, but i ask you if it's possibile without install cross-env globally

Answer (score 0):

You can define the environment variable as you run npm.  Like this:

```
OTHER=1000 npm run start
```

npm picks it up and passes it to the script.

Or you can predefine it. Like this (sh, bash)

```
export OTHER=1000
npm run start
```

If you're on a windows cmd shell, try this

```
set OTHER=1000
npm run start
```

Comment: no, i can't,  because i use a window and OTHER=10000 npm run start, response with OTHER is unreconized...